# I'm learning functional programming & i'm wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Tags: php, arrays, functional-programming

Is there a more "functional" way to do this? Yes i know it's PHP and i'm trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. I'm trying to be more functional minded even though it's not a functional language.

```
$c = [];
foreach ($classes as $cl) {
    $c[$cl->Id] = $cl->Name;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the input of `classes` is but you could try one of the many array_ functions such as: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is array_column.

Array_column can isolate a column in an array and set the key name with the third parameter.

```
$c= array_column($classes, 'Name', 'Id');
```

Comment: This is perfect...edited it to include the comma between $classes and 'Name' args.

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistake

Answer (score 1):

I would use this function:

```
$c = array_column($classes, 'Name', 'Id');
```

Answer (score 0):

"Functional" way will be like this:

```
$result = array_reduce(
    $classes,
    function ($t, $cl) {
        $t[$cl->Id] = $cl->Name;

        return $t;
    },
    []
);
```